# eval() with file_get_contents() .. different results

Tags: php, json, eval, file-get-contents

I am trying to use eval() with json_decode(file_get_contents()) and am getting what appears to be different results when eval'ing and hard-coding the values. Am I just missing something easy?

I am using PHP Version 5.3.24, and do not have the ability to change at the moment. If it is critical to eval() support, I can start the process of getting it changed. I have not found anything that suggests I do not have eval() support in my current PHP implementation.

When I run Example1('key') I get NULL back from the eval() function. When I run Example2('key') I get back an array based on json data that looks like this:

```
{ key_list: [ { data1_list: [ { subkey1: "data", subkey2: 0 }, .. ], .. ] }
```

Here is Example1():

```
function Example1($key) {

    $endPoint = 'http:'.'//some.website.com/json/'.$key;

    $evalCommand = sprintf('json_decode(file_get_contents("%s"))->%s_list[0];', $endPoint, $key);

    echo '$evalCommand = |'.$evalCommand.'|<br />';

    $resultsArray = eval($evalCommand);

    return $resultsArray;
}
```

Here is Example2():

```
function Example2($key) {

    $endPoint = 'http:'.'//some.website.com/json/'.$key;

    $resultsArray = json_decode(file_get_contents($endPoint))->key_list[0];

    return $resultsArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `eval`, it may be able to use more standard code and using dynamic object access.

The name of the URL is OK, but for the field there is a bit of juggling.  This sets the name in `$field`, but I couldn't get it to do that part and the array part in one line.  Here it uses `->$field` to get the data and the `[0]` is on the return...

```
function Example2($key) {
    $endPoint = 'http://some.website.com/json/'.$key;

    $field = $key.'_list';
    $resultsArray = json_decode(file_get_contents($endPoint))->$field;

    return $resultsArray[0];
}
```